# Firebase transaction is not repeating on failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

**UPDATE:**

This is the `console.error(err)` message i get:

```
Error: 6 ALREADY_EXISTS: Document already exists: projects/projectOne-e3999/databases/(default)/documents/storage/AAAAAAAAAA1111111111
```

I do get why I get the error. Because a transaction running in parallel was faster executing the `else` Part of the transaction. So the transaction that is returning the error does not have to create but to update the document. It would be enough if the transaction woul re-run. But it does not altough it states `Transactions are committed once 'updateFunction' resolves and attempted up to five times on failure`.

And that is the whole point of the question. How can i prevent the transaction from failing when the document already exists, because it was created in parallel or how to re-run the transaction?

**Original Question:**

I have a cloud function that updates another document whenever a document in another collection gets created. As there can be multiple documents created in parallel which all access the same document this will run as transaction, idempotance is insured.

The structure of the function looks like the following. The problem is the very first write (so the creation of the storage doc). As i've said two documents can get created in parallel. But now the transaction reads a document which is not there and tries to create it, but as the other transaction (parallel running one) already created the document the transaction fails. (Which i do not understand in the first place, as I thought the transaction will block all access while executing)

This is not a problem at all, but it does not retry (although it states it will retry up to 5 times automatically). I think this has to do something with my try & catch block for the async function.

If it would retry it would detect that the document exists and automatically update the existing one.

Let's put it simple. This transaction must never fail. It would leave the database inconsistent without a possible automatic way to recover.

```
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        //Handle idempotence
        const eventId = context.eventId;
        try {
            const process = await shouldProcess(eventId)
            if (!process) {
                return null
            }

            const storageDoc = admin.firestore().doc(`storage/${snapshot.id}`)

           
            await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async t => {
                    const storageDbDoc = await storageDoc.get()
                    const dataDb = storageDbDoc.data()

                    if (dataDb) {
                        //For sake of testing just rewrite it
                        t.update(storageDoc, dataDb )
                    } else {
                        //Create new     
                        const storage = createStorageDoc()
                        t.create(storageDoc, storage )    
                    }
            })
            return markProcessed(eventId)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Execution of ${eventId} failed: ${err}`)
            throw new Error(`Transaction failed.`);
        }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show more detail about the failure other than just "transaction failed".  You should log the error object in its entirety, not just a string representation.  `console.error(err)`.

Comment: Basic point: Transactions do NOT block anything at all.  They *DO* check to see if any documents read during the transaction processing have since changed.  If any document read *has* changed, the results are *not* committed and the entire transaction is re-tried.  Most critically: nothing is locked, nothing is blocked.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#runtransaction

Comment: @DougStevenson i updated the question with the log, maybe the question now is a bit clearer.

Comment: @LeadDreamer Okay, that explains WHY I get the error. Now the question is: How do I prevent this from happening. I really only need one single transaction ever (the first one ever) create the document. All other should just update the existing document. (Even if there are multiple transactions running in parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction insists on being able to create a new document:

```
t.create(storageDoc, storage)
```

Since [create()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#create) fails on the condition of the document already existing, the entire transaction simply fails, without the ability to recover.

If your transaction must be able to recover, you should check if that document exists prior to trying to write it, and decide what you want to do in that case.

Comment: So what you are saying is: get the document AGAIN before trying to create it? Because I already got at at the very beginning of the transaction, did I not? Why does the transaction then say 'it will repeat up to 5 times on failure'?

Comment: You have to use the transaction object to read the doc.  You can't do it with a normal `get()` on the reference.  Use `t.get(ref)` instead so the transaction knows you want to lock that document. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get

Comment: Oh my god. I did NOT see this. Jesus. Thank you. I will try in the morning. I do know that I have to use the transaction object, I just did not see that I didn't. I will reply if this was indeed the (very simple) solution

Comment: I tested this now multiple times. It seems that this problem was the root of all evil. Thank you, sometimes another person has to state the obvious

Comment: @LeadDreamer If you have a question, please post it separately.